# QGraphicsView not zooming in

Tags: qt, scale, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I am using Qt 5.7 and have a `QGraphicsView` in which I have added a `QSceneView`. At the program start, I fit the scene into the view with `fitinview` and `Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio` (maybe this is relevant?). I am trying to create an interface for zooming in and out with 4 simple buttons. To zoom out horizontally for example I call `view.scale(0.5,1)`.

However, if I try to zoom on in any axis by using scale factors larger than 1, nothing happens. It's as if I didn't even click the button, as no matter how often I pressed zoomed in, I can zoom out with one click. Somehow the `scale` method is being completely ignored if the value is greater than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was using `fitinview` and `Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio`. I removed the call and everything works perfectly now.